# mouse-over only on actual data points

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

Here's a really simple line chart.

```
%matplotlib notebook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

lines = plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 4, 9, 16])
plt.setp(lines,marker='D')
plt.ylabel('foo')
plt.xlabel('bar')
plt.show()
```

If I move my mouse over the chart, I get the x and y values for wherever the pointer is. Is there any way to only get values only when I'm actually over a data point?

Comment: You can check if your mouse is over an artist which is drawn in the plot. A datapoint itself has no extention so, not sure how that would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood you wanted to modify the behavior of the coordinates displayed in the status bar at the bottom right of the plot, is that right?

If so, you can "hijack" the `Axes.format_coord()` function to make it display whatever you want. You can see [an example of this](https://matplotlib.org/examples/api/image_zcoord.html) on matplotlib's example gallery.

In your case, something like this seem to do the trick?

```
my_x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
my_y = np.array([1, 4, 9, 16])
eps = 0.1

def format_coord(x, y):
    close_x = np.isclose(my_x, x, atol=eps)
    close_y = np.isclose(my_y, y, atol=eps)
    if np.any(close_x) and np.any(close_y):
        return 'x=%s y=%s' % (ax.format_xdata(my_x[close_x]), ax.format_ydata(my_y[close_y]))
    else:
        return ''

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(my_x, my_y, 'D-')
ax.set_ylabel('foo')
ax.set_xlabel('bar')
ax.format_coord = format_coord

plt.show()
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks. Am I reading this correctly, that it basically suppresses the x and y values if the mouse isn't over one of the data points?

Comment: That's right, and outputs the value of the data point instead of the actual mouse coordinates when you are close to a datapoint